# Full image is not showing in carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is there any way to display a full image in a bootstrap carousel. I want the container to take the full size of the image but it cuts it short at the bottom.

```css
.carousel-indicators li{
    width: 10px !important;
    height: 10px !important;
    border-radius: 100% !important;
}
#hero {
    position: relative;
}

#course-form{
    
}
#carousel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.carousel-inner,
.carousel-item {
    height: 100%;
    
}
.carousel-item {
    background: no-repeat center/cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
    height: 30vh;
    width: 15vw;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid hero" id="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-6 mb-4">
      <img src="./images/logo.png" class="logo">
      <button id="signup"><span id="signup-icon"></span>Sign Up</button>
           <button id="signin"><span id="signin-icon"></span>Sign In</button>
      <div class="box">
         <div class="container-1">
             <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
             <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
         </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--row for logo,search, and form -->
   <!-- Here is the carousel, `position:absolute` -->
   <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image:url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/plant-growing-picture-id510222832?k=6&m=510222832&s=612x612&w=0&h=Pzjkj2hf9IZiLAiXcgVE1FbCNFVmKzhdcT98dcHSdSk=')"></div>

     <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url('http://www.electran.org/publication/transactiontrends/wp-content/uploads/intelligence-growth-1050x700.jpg')">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url('http://www.globoforce.com/gfblog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/sprouting-seed.jpg')">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!-- container for top image carousel -->
 </div>
```

I tried tweaking the .carousel-inner css to take the full size of the image but I have not had any luck. I have tried background-contain and cover but not luck as of yet

updated with images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your

```
.carosel-item {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I believe that is what you are looking for!
Cheers

UPDATE:
After reviewing your question what you are after is a parent wrapper to be of image size. As far as my knowledge  goes you can't size the wrapper (parent container) based on background image size.

What you can do instead is set your parent wrapper size with `width:` and `height:` attributes, and `css` for carosel-item will do the rest.

Best of luck with your development.

Comment: could you update your image path so we can see how it looks?

Comment: @dutchkillsg ok one more try.. give it a go.. please update your image path as well so we can see the snippet

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. You want your wrap (container) to be same size as the image? @dutchkillsg

Comment: Yes I want my container to take the full size of the image

Comment: @dutchkillsg I have updated the answer with some new notes

Comment: @dutchkillsg How is this different to `background: no-repeat center/cover;` already present in the question and provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372182/3897122) as well?